# How can I determine if mbrace is installed in car?

Tags: mercedes-benz

I bought a 2012 Mercedes S550 secondhand.

How can I tell if it has mbrace in it?

(this is a vehicle data recording and transmitting system)

Comment: From what I can see, mbrace has only been available since 2013. If yours is a 2012, I'm betting it wasn't an option on your vehicle, therefore it wouldn't have it. There is the mbrace version for 2013-2015, then a newer version for 2016 and newer. You can find more information [here](https://www.mbusa.com/en/mbrace2).

Comment: BTW, it appears to me mbrace is MB's version of Onstar (GM product which has been around for quite some time), yet also includes an entertainment and information portion of it as well. Depending on the package level you purchase (or pay for), it can provide quite a bit of "stuff". While it may do vehicle data, I'm thinking it does a heck of a lot more than that.